# Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks (dynamic import)

Tags: reactjs

```
const usePage = ({ page }) => {
  const prevPage = usePrevious(page)

  const [p, setPage] = useState()

  const loadData = async param => {
    const data = await import(`${param}`)
    setPage(data.default)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (prevPage === page) return

    loadData(page)
  }, [page, prevPage])

  return {
    p
  }
}

const PageRoute = memo(({page}) => {
    const { p } = usePage({ page })

    const Page = p

    return (
      <Page/>
    )
  }
)
```

I don't really understand how do this issue related to my code . I don't call any hook inside `useEffect`. How can I fix it ? I want to call dynamic import in use effect in case when page parameter are not equal previous one.

Comment: You do. `useEffect` calls `loadData`  and there is `setPage` hook.

Comment: @slawciu that's not the same - setPage is not a hook but a setter function returned by the useState hook.

Comment: How can I rewrite it to make it work ? @slawciu

Comment: @AndreyRadkevich Although this might be irrelevant but after looking at your code, I think `React.lazy()` might help you. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: I use server side rendering @VishnuSingh

Comment: Oh Sorry! SSR is not supported by them as of now.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that since you're probably exporting a React component as default from these dynamically imported modules, `data.default` is a function which gets passed to the setter returned by `useState`.

However, since the `useState` setter can also take in a [function which does the state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), what's happening is that the setter calls the passed function which is a React component (`data.default`) which fires the hooks used in that component. So your call is actually equivalent to `setPage(prev => data.default(prev))`.

This can be fixed by explicitly passing your own state updater which just returns the `data.default` function:

```
const loadData = async param => {
  const data = await import(`${param}`)
  setPage(() => data.default) // <-------
}
```

Comment: I know, instead of commenting like that, we should upvote the answer (which I already did) but what a brilliant catch!

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get around this by encapsulating my state in a separate sub component

### component called from useMemo:

```
export function DeleteColumn<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>>({ onClick }: Props<T>) {
  return {
    ...
    Header: "Delete",
    className: "...",
    Cell: (cell: Cell<T>) => {
      return ConfirmPopup<T>(onClick, cell)
    },
  }
}
```

#### sub component

```
function ConfirmPopup<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>>(
  onClick: ((val: T) => void) | undefined,
  cell: Cell<T, any>
) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      {onClick && (
        <Popover2
          ...
          isOpen={isOpen}
          ...
          content={
            ...
          }
        >
          <Button  ... />
        </Popover2>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```