# React Native Conditional Rendering - Swapping Template Syntax

Tags: react-native

I need to conditionally render one of 3 templates. The way I want it set up is as I describe: Login Form (default) -> Register Form (when click Register button) -> Login Form (after click Register button on Register template) -> Manage Account template.

I have read and tried implementing the suggested way of doing this as mentioned in this document here: https://www.reactnative.express/react/conditional_rendering.

But, it is not working properly.

**Edit Update:** I've implemented the code in the accepted answer but the computer is throwing an error that reads: `Warning: Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks. You can only call Hooks at the top level of your React function. For more information, see:` https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Linking} from 'react-native';
import EditScreenInfo from '../../components/EditScreenInfo';
import { Text  } from '../../components/Themed';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Constants } from '../../constants/Constants';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


const [showRegisterForm, setShowRegisterForm] = useState(false);
const [showLoginForm, setLoginForm ] = useState(false);
const [showManageProfile, setManageProfile ] = useState(true);

const StackOverflowAnswer = () => {
  if (showRegisterForm) {
    return (
      <View><Text>Register Form.</Text></View>
    );
  } else if (showLoginForm) {
    return (
      <View><Text>Login Form.</Text></View>

    );
  } else if(showManageProfile){
      <View><Text>Manage Profile.</Text></View>
  }
  else {
    <View><Text>Login Form.</Text></View>
  }
};

export default function TabOneScreen() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

  const [showRegisterForm, setShowRegisterForm] = useState(false)
  const [afterRegister, setAfterRegister] = useState(false)
  const [afterLogin, setAfterLogin] = useState(false)
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("")
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState("")
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState("")
  const [userPassword, setUserPassword] = useState("")
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState("")
  const [stripeConnectAcctId, setStripeConnectAcctId] = useState("")

  const subdomain = Constants.Subdomain;

  const onPressLogin = async () => {
    console.log('email: ', email);
    console.log('password: ', password);

    var req_json = { Email: email, Password: password};

    console.log(req_json);

    var headers = 
    { 
      headers: 
      { 
          //"Authorization" : `Bearer ${auth_token}`, 
          "Accept" : "*/*",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          "Host": subdomain + ".conveyor.cloud"
      }
    };

    //await axios.get('https://' + subdomain + '.conveyor.cloud/Account/Login/?email=' + email + "&password=" + password);

    // acquire token, set that in javascript as a cookie/save it globally and refer to it
    var req_json2 = {username: email, password: password, grant_type: 'password'}

    var headers2 = 
    { 
      headers: 
      { 
          //"Authorization" : `Bearer ${auth_token}`, 
          "Accept" : "*/*",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          "Host": subdomain + ".conveyor.cloud"
      }
    };

    const resp = await axios.post('https://' + subdomain + '.conveyor.cloud/token', req_json2, headers2);
    
    const token = resp.data.access_token;

    if(token != null && token != "") {
      console.log("auth_token: " + token);
      AsyncStorage.setItem('auth_token', token);
      AsyncStorage.setItem('senderEmail', email);
    }
    
    setAfterLogin(true)
  }

  const showRegistrationForm = () => {
    setShowRegisterForm(true);
  }

  const stripeOnboarding = async () => {
    var headers = 
    { 
      headers: 
      { 
          //"Authorization" : `Bearer ${auth_token}`, 
          "Accept" : "*/*",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          "Host": subdomain + ".conveyor.cloud"
      }
    };

    const resp = await axios.post('https://' + subdomain + '.conveyor.cloud/Home/CreateStripeAccount', {}, headers);
    
    console.log(resp.data.connectedAccountId, resp.data.onboardingUrl)

    if(resp) {
     setStripeConnectAcctId(resp.data.connectedAccountId);

     const auth_token = AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_token');
     const senderEmail = AsyncStorage.getItem('senderEmail');
     
     const req_json = {email: senderEmail, stripeConnectedAcctId: resp.data.connectedAccountId };

      var headers2 = 
      { 
        headers: 
        { 
            "Authorization" : `Bearer ${auth_token}`, 
            "Accept" : "*/*",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Host": subdomain + ".conveyor.cloud"
        }
      };
  
      const resp2 = await axios.post('https://' + subdomain + '.conveyor.cloud/Account/SaveStripeAcctId', req_json, headers2);

      if (await Linking.canOpenURL(resp.data.onboardingUrl)) {
        await Linking.openURL(resp.data.onboardingUrl);
      }
    }
  }

  const submitRegistrationForm = async () => {
    var req_json = {
      FirstName: firstName, 
      LastName: lastName,
      Email: userEmail,
      Password: userPassword,
      ConfirmPassword: confirmPassword
    }

    var headers = 
    { 
      headers: 
      { 
          //"Authorization" : `Bearer ${auth_token}`, 
          "Accept" : "*/*",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          "Host": subdomain + ".conveyor.cloud"
      }
    };

    const resp = await axios.post('https://' + subdomain + '.conveyor.cloud/Account/Register', req_json, headers);

    setAfterRegister(true)
  }

  return (
    <StackOverflowAnswer />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  separator: {
    marginVertical: 30,
    height: 1,
    width: '80%',
  },
  inputView:{
    width:"80%",
    backgroundColor:"#3AB4BA",
    borderRadius:25,
    height:50,
    marginBottom:20,
    justifyContent:"center",
    padding:20
  },
  inputText:{
    height:50,
    color:"white"
  },
  loginBtn: {
    
  },
  registerBtn: {
    marginTop:35,
    padding:8,
    borderColor:'black',
    borderWidth:2,
    borderRadius:5
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderColor: '#fff',
    borderWidth:2,
    padding: 10,
    elevation: 2,
    marginTop: 15,
    color:'black'
  },
  registerFormField: {
    margin:8,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 2,
    padding:5
  }
});
```

How might I modify the code to achieve the desired behavior mentioned above?

Thank you.

Comment: The styling is not really relevant to your question, if you take it out your code will became more readable. Have a look here for how to create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the conditional render a separate function. Additionally instead of afterLogin and afterRegister I'd make variables for each thing you want to show and track it that way. If you want to show login form have showLoginForm = true. When I ran into a similar problem for an app I am developing and went with something like this:

```
  const StackOverflowAnswer = () => {
    if (showRegisterForm) {
      return (
        {/**  Your register code here */}
      );
    } else if (showLoginForm) {
      return (
        {/**  Your login code here */}

      );
    } else {
        {/**  Your form code here */}
    }
  };
```

Then to use this in the main functions return add this to your code wherever you'd like the forms to show up:

```
 <StackOverflowAnswer />
```

If each different form is fairly large/different to the others you could also separate them out into entirely different screens and then navigate to each one at the appropriate time. It would also make your code more readable by shortening each individual file and separating your concerns out.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. How would you go about navigating between screens at the appropriate time then? I don't want to show the Register screen as a tab. I just want one Login tab with a Register button on it. Then, to navigate to the Manage Profile tab.

Comment: Use react native navigation, see documentation here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation

Comment: I tried using your suggested answer brother... but the computer ended up throwing this error: Warning: Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks. You can only call Hooks at the top level of your React function. For more information, see https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks. Have you seen this before? Do you know how to handle this one?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62809968/do-not-call-hooks-inside-useeffect-usememo-or-other-built-in-hooks

Comment: I don’t understand how this solves my problem. Just need this last piece. Could you conjure a working expo snack?